# Wrap-around CSS border animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to obtain a wrap-around-like border animation with pure CSS.

The way I'm doing it now is with `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements size changing. One for the top and right border, and one for the bottom and left one.

However, due to the difference in width and height I'm getting a weird effect because each side takes equal time, but as the width is much larger than the height it looks like it goes much faster.

How would you go about fixing it without knowing the size of the div beforehand?

Also any different approach to obtain the same animation with SCSS/vanilla CSS is also welcome.

Seems like I can't change the size of the snippet on SO, but here is a codepen if you wanna play around: https://codepen.io/lollobaldo2000/pen/KKPazNw?editors=1100

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

.square {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -100px auto auto -250px;
}
.square:before, .square:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #FB0;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.square:before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  animation: btm 2s ease-in forwards;
}
.square:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  animation: btm 2s 2s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes btm {
  0% {
visibility: visible;
width: 0;
height: 0;
  }
  50% {
width: 100%;
height: 0;
  }
  100% {
width: 100%;
height: calc(100% - 1px);
visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can easily do this considering a small SVG that you use to define the border then you animate the `stroke-dashoffset`

```css
.square {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:5px;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align:top;
}


svg {
 overflow:visible;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

rect {
 fill:transparent;
 stroke:#FB0;
 stroke-dasharray: 1000;
 stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
 animation:change 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes change {
  to {
   stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
<svg  preserveAspectRatio="none"><rect x=0 y=0 width=100% height=100% /></svg>
</div>


<div class="square" style="width:100px;">
<svg  preserveAspectRatio="none"><rect x=0 y=0 width=100% height=100% /></svg>
</div>


<div class="square" style="height:250px;">
<svg  preserveAspectRatio="none"><rect x=0 y=0 width=100% height=100% /></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great. Any way I could add it as a background so not to have the `<svg>` tag in my HTML?

Comment: @Lorenzo you can add the SVG as background but you will not be able to trigger the aniamtion on a background. You are obliged to have it as an element to run the animation

Comment: Upvote as it pointed me in the right direction. I did a little dig around and it turns out there are multiple ways of including `<style>` into an svg. Have a look at the answer I'm adding

Answer (score 1):

As @Temani said, SVGs are the way to go. You can just insert the style including the animations into the svg itself. I added it as an inline `url()`. Note it as to be escaped for certain characters:

```css
body{background:black;}
.square{
width: 300px;
height:100px;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3e%3cstyle%3e rect %7b fill: transparent; stroke: %23FF9800; stroke-dasharray: 1000; stroke-dashoffset: 1000; animation:change 3s ease-in-out forwards; stroke-width: 5;%7d %40keyframes change %7b to %7b stroke-dashoffset: 0;%7d %7d %3c/style%3e%3crect width='100%25' height='100%25' /%3e%3c/svg%3e ");
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
</div>
```